# when to use Classes vs Objects vs Case Classes vs Traits

Tags: scala

This is what I understood so far.

Classes should be used when we need to instantialte objects

We use "Objects" only when we have a singleton requirement meaning no need for multiple instances of "objects". I am thinking when we are building common library functions or utility functions in a project, we can use "objects" that way we need to instantiate each time we use methods/functions in that Object.

Case classes can be used when we want to save boilerplate code. Say we have "Stock" class. Each stock in general has hundreds of member variables. Instead of developer writing code for setters and getters, if we case class, it generates lot of default code.

Traits: don't know when to use. Both Traits and Objects don't take parameters during initialization.

Any more thoughts and ideas kindly share.

Comment: If you want to enforce class invariants, use a regular class, not a case class.

Answer (score 25):

In Scala classes act like in any other OO-language (e.g. Java) too - that is you use classes to build objects (not Scala Objects) in your applications, which have a state (e.g. holding attributes, say a name of a Person).

Scala Objects are singletons. You use it in Scala mainly for

- creating functions/artifacts, which do not need a state/belong to a specific object. In other OO-languages you use the static keyword for this behavior.
- providing factory methods (especially via the apply method) to instantiate classes (see Scala companion objects)

Case classes are intended to be used as lightweight classes (e.g. datacontainers). They are immutable by default and supposed to be structurally be compared (that is by comparing the values/state) and not by reference.
Additionally, they provide features like serialization out of the box.

Traits are like interfaces in Java with some more features. They define the interface of a class/object.

Before you start to dive deeper in Scala, I'd recommend being first familiar with classic OO principles.